# LeafletSlider and timestamp

Tags: jquery, leaflet, slider

I am using Leaflet and the plugin **LeafletSlider** (https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) to show some markers on a map. Markers are stored in JSON file.

As you can see on [the map](http://trovawiki.altervista.org/pride2023.html), the plugin works fine: moving the slider the markers appear.

I would like to **show the slider timestamp** (beside or below the slider) to make visualization more clear.
On the plugin documentation I found no info. Maybe there is a jQuery workaround.